# Scale values of a particular column of python dataframe between 1-10

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scale, normalization

I have a dataframe which contains youtube videos views, I want to scale these values in the range of 1-10. 
Below is the sample of how values look like? How do i normalize it in the range of 1-10 or is there any more efficient way to do this thing?

```
rating
4394029
274358
473691
282858
703750
255967
3298456
136643
796896
2932
220661
48688
4661584
2526119
332176
7189818
322896
188162
157437
1153128
788310
1307902
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is performing a scaling with `max`.

```
1 + df / df.max() * 9

       rating
0    6.500315
1    1.343433
2    1.592952
3    1.354073
4    1.880933
5    1.320412
6    5.128909
7    1.171046
8    1.997531
9    1.003670
10   1.276217
11   1.060946
12   6.835232
13   4.162121
14   1.415808
15  10.000000
16   1.404192
17   1.235536
18   1.197075
19   2.443451
20   1.986783
21   2.637193
```

---

Similar solution by Wen (now deleted):

```
1 + (df - df.min()) * 9 / (df.max() - df.min())

       rating
0    6.498887
1    1.339902
2    1.589522
3    1.350546
4    1.877621
5    1.316871
6    5.126922
7    1.167444
8    1.994266
9    1.000000
10   1.272658
11   1.057299
12   6.833941
13   4.159739
14   1.412306
15  10.000000
16   1.400685
17   1.231960
18   1.193484
19   2.440368
20   1.983514
21   2.634189
```

Comment: OP says they want 1-10, not 0-10.

Comment: it should be 1-10

Comment: @NikitaGupta What about now?

Comment: I delete my , since it is similar ,`1+(df-df.min())*9/(df.max()-df.min())`

Comment: @Wen It looks correct and gives the (almost) same result, so I added it as an alternative. :-)

Comment: when there is negative number , the result should be different :-)